# Python histogram plotting a bin which doesn't exist in the dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am running the following script to plot some data using Matplotlib within Jupyter Notebook. I am using Matplotlib version 1.5.1 and Numpy version 1.10.4 on Python 2.7.11 running within Jupyter Notebook 4.1.0 installed as part of an Anaconda 4.0.0 installation.

However, the linear histogram plotted a very small bin which didn't exist in the dataset. This "pseudo-bin" didn't show up on the log histogram, and checking the data shows that there is no data with value less than -5 (the `print` statement returns an empty list).

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(relEnergy,bins=np.arange(-10,0))
plt.show()
plt.hist(relEnergy,bins=np.arange(-10,0),log=True)
plt.show()
print [x for x in relEnergy if x<-5]
```

The two plots are shown below, with the offending plot (bin circled in red) shown with a log plot which is working as expected.

[image]

I was able to narrow down the issue, running the script

```
plt.hist([-3.7006499999999991, -3.2990499999999994],bins=np.arange(-10,0))
plt.show()
```

also results in this phantom bin.

[image]

Why was this bin created, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: What is `import matplotlib; matplotlib.__version__`  on your system?